# Audio not playing when Objects clicked C# Unity

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

My .wav sound file is not playing when it is called to play. The sound file is working because when I select "Play On Awake" in the Audio Source component, the sound file is played. It is also played if I call hit.Play(); in both the Start and Update methods. It is not, however, played inside my OnMouseOver or OnMouseDown methods; even though they are in perfect working condition otherwise.

I have done plentiful research only to run into deprecated code or solutions that simply don't solve my problem; so if anyone has any insight on my issue some help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class clickDissapear : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioSource hit;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    hit.Play();
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}

private void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        hit.Play();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        hit.Play();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

private void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    //Play Miss
}

void Start () {
    hit = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update () {

    }
}
```

[Here is a screenshot of my setup in Unity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JrGk.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the sound is played and the object WITH THE AUDIOSOURCE is destoryed. That's why you don't hear any sound. The audioSource is destroyed and you only hear the first .001 seconds of the sound. I suggest you use Destroy(this.gameobject, hit.audioclip.Lenght); or a Coroutine.

Comment: Ah I see, That makes sense. I thought that if the audio queued up before the destruction, it would play out the entire clip regardless of the state of the object.

Comment: Hope one of the 2 solutions solves you the problem as you would like to. Also you might attach the audioSource to an other object if you want. Maybe it's parent for easier finding